# Are my display problems for non-gaming due to my graphic card?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

I wanted to ask about troubleshooting a graphics/display issue with 4K - no specific advice on buying choices.  I hope my question is clear, to troubleshoot a display problem. Please ignore anything that seems to deviate from that focal point of my argument. I realize I can sometimes take up a great deal of space compared to others with their questions.

I remember a time being told that if I wasn't building a gaming machine?  I have a Ryzen 7 1700 system with 16GB DDR4 RAM.  I have two monitors, one is like a 2.5K (slightly higher than HD 2K).  The other is a 4K monitor.  None of my Windows 10 settings are set to turn off the monitor display after like 1 to 2 minutes, but that is what is happening.  It happens on both monitors or even if I unplug the lower resolution monitor.

Could this be an issue of not having a sufficiently large power supply?  I have a 650W Power Supply.  As far as calculating power requirements, I have CPU, motherboard, fans, video card and 4 HDD disk drives, not SSD.

So, the main question is with regard to the video card.  I'm not doing gaming or even video editing, etc. I have an AMD Radeon R9 270X.  I've had it for a while.  It has the latest drivers.  Could it be not powerful enough?  If I rule out power requirements and the capabilities of this card to work with 4K, then the obvious conclusion must be the card is getting old and dying, i.e. becoming defective.

Apparently, the Ryzen CPUs want a dedicated graphics card whereas the APUs which include graphics capabilities.  It's too bad they couldn't figure out how to build an APU without sacrificing on the CPU performance.  I guess die size and socket compatibility were factors in that.

So, in summary, I do need a graphics card, right?  And does 4K demand a more powerful graphics card in general?  I'm not asking for specific buying choices, just troubleshooting tips.

Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: I would monitor the heat numbers on the graphics card for a while,  Do they rise over time before the monitors shut off?  How is your system cooling set up?  Do your monitors come back on after a while, or does the system just die?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems more like an issue that was introduced after a Windows 10 update, where a new default for power options shut the display or entered sleep after a minute or two. Make sure all power settings are shown.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type `button`.
- Select `Change what he power buttons do`.

[image: Show all power settings]

- Select `Change settings that are currently unavailable`.
- Check `Sleep`, `Hibernate` and `Lock`.
- Save changes.
- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type `power`.
- Select `Edit power plan`.

[image: Select advanced power settings]

- Select `Change advanced power settings`.
- Finally, walk through all the power-saving options such as `Display` and change any setting that might be shutting things down early.

[image: Display power settings]